# Didn't mark that I had a checking account for direct deposit on tax filing, will I have my returns rejected?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax-refund, turbotax

I submitted by taxes electronically through TurboTax and I realized that when I submitted my bank info in order to receive my returns via direct deposit, I didn't mark that it was a checking account and it has a blank in that area. My other info is correct, so I was wondering if they will reject my filing, or will they accept it but without that info, I will get a check instead.

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: United States of america

Comment: If deposit fails, you should receive a check. Surprising that TurboTax allowed submitting a return with empty account type field.

Comment: @void_ptr Welcome to money.SE! On this site, we [avoid answering questions in the comments](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/refund-inquiries/refund-inquiries-18), if the bank refuses the deposit due to an error on the tax return, the IRS will mail a check to your address.

> **Scenario:**
>
> - You omit a digit in the account or routing number of an account and the number doesn't pass the IRS's validation check. In this case, the IRS will send you a paper check for the entire refund instead of a direct deposit.
> - You incorrectly enter an account or routing number and the number passes the validation check but your designated financial institution rejects and returns the deposit to the IRS. The IRS will issue a paper check for that portion of your refund once received.

Comment: So I assume this would include my scenario?

Comment: @Asking I would assume that, yes. You did get the account numbers right, so either the bank will accept the deposit or not. If the bank refuses the deposit, the IRS won’t know why; they’ll just assume that you typed the account number incorrectly and mail you a check. Or because you left the account type blank, the info will fail the IRS validation requirements and they’ll mail you a check without even trying to deposit.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll wait and see